# Waht's the difference between 'Adam' and 'tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)'

Tags: python

There are two optimizers.

1.

```py
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

2. 

```py
    lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate=float(os.getenv("initial_learning_rate")),
        decay_steps=int(os.getenv("decay_steps")),
        decay_rate=float(os.getenv("decay_rate"))
    )
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I used the first one, the accuracy rate was increasing rapidly.
while the second one makes the accuracy almost no changeable.